# Find all such $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $1=a_1,a_2,...,a_k=n$ be all its divisors. Find all $m$ such that $2=a_1+1,a_2+1,...,a_k+1$ are all the divisors for some $m$ except $1$ and $m$. Find all such $n$.

I tried small numbers but it seems like there doesn't exist such $n$.

Let $D_m$ be all the divisors of $m$ except $1$ and $m$, then $$m=lcm(D_m)$$

On the other hand, for $k\ge 4$ we have $n=a_1a_k=a_2a_{k-1}=...$
And a similar result for $m$ so $m=2(n+1)$. Now I want to find a divisor of the lcm that doesn't divide $2(n+1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark list of divisors of $n$ as $A$, and list of $a_i+1$ as $B$.

Let's consider four cases: $n=1$, $n=2$, $n$ is odd prime, and $n$ is composite.

$n=1$, $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$, $m=4$. OK.

$n=2$, $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$, $m=6$. OK.

$n$ is odd prime, $n=p$, $A=\{1,p\}$, $B=\{2,p+1\}$, $m=2(p+1)$ is divisible by 4 and $m$ is greater than 4, then $B$ must include 4, then $p+1=4$, $p=3$. The only satisfactory odd prime is $n=3$. $A=\{1,3\}$, $B=\{2,4\}$, $m=8$. OK.

$n$ is composite. Let $p$ is minimum prime factor of $n$ and $n=pk$, $k>1$. Then $A=\{1,p,...,k,pk\}$, $B=\{2,p+1,...k+1,pk+1\}$. Then $m=2(pk+1)=(p+1)(k+1) \Rightarrow$ $pk+1=p+k \Rightarrow k=\frac{p-1}{p-1}=1$, which is contradictory.

Answer: $n=1$, $n=2$, $n=3$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $n$ composite (that's why I said it seems that there doesn't exist such $n$) But your answer  covers all cases.